# Owl carousel 2 not working after api call

Tags: javascript, api, youtube-api, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

I am taking some data from youtube API but when i am using the following code. Owl carousel not working.

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics,contentDetails&id=" + get_video_id + "&key=" + api_key + "";
$.get(url, function(value) {

    if (value.items[0] != undefined) {
        var video_viewers = value.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
        single_carousel_container.append('<div class="single-video"><h3 class="video-view">' + video_viewers + '</h3>/div>');

    }
});
owl_active();

function owl_active() {
    single_carousel_container.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            margin: 30,
        }
    });
}
```

[image]

But if i remove the api call then owl carousel working properly. So how i can use owl carousel 2 with youtube api call?

**Full Source Code : https://pastebin.com/bKeLYbZv**

Comment: The `$.get` call is async. You are trying to activate before it's loaded. put `owl_active()` inside the `if` statement.

Comment: Yes.. i can use that inside $.get but there have another $.get outside of that statement to get some others api data + that in inside a .each function.
Full code : https://pastebin.com/bKeLYbZv

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing the owl carousel before data fetching is finished and attached into container.

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=statistics,contentDetails&id=" + get_video_id + "&key=" + api_key + "";

function owl_active() {
    single_carousel_container.owlCarousel({
            loop: true,
            margin: 30,
        }
    });
}

$.get(url, function(value) {

    if (value.items[0] != undefined) {
        var video_viewers = value.items[0].statistics.viewCount;
        single_carousel_container.append('<div class="single-video"><h3 class="video-view">' + video_viewers + '</h3>/div>');
        owl_active();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

After you modify the HTML of the slider (via prepend, append, etc) you need to let OwlCarousel know that the HTML has been modified triggering the `refresh.owl.carousel` event on the carousel element.

Not to be confused with the `refreshed.owl.carousel` event, which is automatically fired once your slider has been updated.

Docs: https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-events.html#refresh-owl-carousel

Comment: can you give me an example for that?  https://pastebin.com/bKeLYbZv